# constantly run into ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error on chrome/mac when switching between vpn and home networks. All the browsers run into this issue

Tags: google-chrome, mac, vpn

[fixed]  constantly run into ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error on chrome/mac when switching between vpn and home network.

Answer (score 4):

As bizarre as it sounds but this is the solution : disconnect your latest updated iPhone from macbook for charing or other reasons. this issue should go away. i learnt this solution the hard way. the problem was very frustrating i tried all the solutions over the internet and even learned few mac networking commands in this process. but year unplugging your phone from  laptop solves this issue. Cheers. at-least that is what worked for me. i was using mac 2019 BigSur and iOS 14.5

solution courtesy : https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/google-chrome-err_network_changed.2197278/post-29652051

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sharath's solution, I found out that even if you have the iPhone remotely connected to your Mac (like as a remote device on Xcode for development) it happens. When unpairing the iPhone from the Xcode device list -  no errors are coming your way anymore.

I have an Apple Sillicon Mac and iPhone 15 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error on MacOS:  Reset your Mac's SMC:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).